# Обновление Dictionary с опозданием - C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, update, словари

Есть вот такой  метод

```
   string db = @"../data/db/base.db3";
    SQLiteFactory sf = (SQLiteFactory)DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SQLite");
    using (SQLiteConnection sc = (SQLiteConnection)sf.CreateConnection())
    {
        sc.ConnectionString = "Data source = " + db;
        sc.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sc))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in result)
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Articles, Counts FROM [Cards] WHERE id_card='" + labelCard.Text + "' AND Articles='" + kvp.Key + "'";
                SQLiteDataReader sr = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (sr.Read())
                {
                    string ar = (string)sr["Articles"];
                    Int64 co = (Int64)sr["Counts"];
                    if (!dbList.ContainsKey(ar))
                    {
                        dbList.Add(ar, Convert.ToInt32(co));
                    }

                }
                sr.Close();

            }

            textBox2.Lines = dbList.Select(x => x.Key + " - " + x.Value).ToArray();
            sc.Close();
        }
```

Берет из базы артикул и количество и загружает в dbList (Dictionary). Сравнивает значение по артикулу с другим Dictionary (result). Если в последнем есть данный артикул, а в dbList нет, то должен из базы выбрать отсутствующий и добавить в dbList. Но срабатывает со второго раза. Допустим если два раза проверку на отсутствующий артикул делать, первый раз - добавления нет, второй раз = добавляет тот что из первой проверки

Comment: мне кажется что textBox2.Lines берёт значение dbList предыдущее, а не новое. В каком месте у тебя создаётся dbList?  Попробуй вынести textBox2 за пределы sc.Close(); Или после dbList.Add